Ogr2ogr Select statement to define new geometry out of given coordinates
I would like to extract and alter place label coordinates from a GML file with cadastral parcel information using ogr2ogr. See part of the GML file at the end of this question.
Besides the given place label coordinates (<oz:plaatscoordinaten> in the gml file), there is a field deltaX and deltaY to shift the label position on the map for presentation reasons. See the image for an example.

In order to recreate the above image, I need to alter the place coordinates by adding deltaX and deltaY and I need to create a LINE with two coordinates: the original place coordinates and the altered place coordinates.
Altogether the requiremenst are:

Convert format from GML to GeoJSON
Convert projection from EPSG:28992 to EPSG:4326
And for all features where deltaX <>0 or deltaY <> 0
Generate altered place coordinates (before converting projecting as deltaX and deltaY are in EPSG:28992 units
Generate line geometry with two coordinates: original place coordinates and altered place coordinates

I assume this requires two runs for ogr2ogr. One to extract the place coordinates and one to generate the line geometries.
I am able to extract the place coordinates with the following ogr2ogr command:
ogr2ogr -lco COORDINATE_PRECISION=7 -f "GeoJSON" kadastralekaart_perceelnummer.geojson -t_srs "EPSG:4326" kadastralekaart_perceel.gml -sql "select perceelnummer,perceelnummerRotatie,deltaX,deltaY from perceel"

But I cannot find out how the select staement should be to alter the coordinates and how the select statement should be to generate the line.
Extract GML file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kk:DKK
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2"
        xmlns:oz="http://www.kadaster.nl/schemas/brkkadastralekaart/v5/imkad-onroerendezaak/v20220601"
        xmlns:h="http://www.kadaster.nl/schemas/brkkadastralekaart/v5/imkad-historie/v20220601"
        xmlns:t="http://www.kadaster.nl/schemas/brkkadastralekaart/v5/imkad-typen/v20220601"
        xmlns:ko="http://www.kadaster.nl/schemas/brkkadastralekaart/v5/imkad-kadastraalobject/v20220601"
        xmlns:q="http://www.kadaster.nl/schemas/brkkadastralekaart/v5/imkad-kwaliteit/v20220601"
        xmlns:kk="http://www.kadaster.nl/schemas/brkkadastralekaart/v5/stand/v20220601"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.kadaster.nl/schemas/brkkadastralekaart/v5/stand/v20220601 http://www.kadaster.nl/schemas/brkkadastralekaart/v5/xsd/dkk/stand/v20220601/DKK-Product_Stand_v5_0_0.xsd">
<kk:perceelMember>
    <oz:Perceel gml:id="NL.IMKAD.KadastraalObject.84920229870000">
        <ko:identificatie domein="NL.IMKAD.KadastraalObject">84920229870000</ko:identificatie>
        <oz:historie>
            <h:beginGeldigheid>2000-11-20T14:29:09+01:00</h:beginGeldigheid>
            <h:tijdstipRegistratie>2000-11-20T14:29:09+01:00</h:tijdstipRegistratie>
            <h:volgnummer>0</h:volgnummer>
            <h:statusHistorie>
                <h:StatusHistorie>
                    <t:code>G</t:code>
                    <t:waarde>Geldig</t:waarde>
                </h:StatusHistorie>
            </h:statusHistorie>
        </oz:historie>
        <oz:kadastraleAanduiding>
            <oz:TypeKadastraleAanduiding>
                <oz:kadastraleGemeente>
                    <oz:KadastraleGemeente>
                        <t:code>761</t:code>
                        <t:waarde>Otterlo</t:waarde>
                    </oz:KadastraleGemeente>
                </oz:kadastraleGemeente>
                <oz:sectie>B</oz:sectie>
                <oz:perceelnummer>2298</oz:perceelnummer>
                <oz:aKRKadastraleGemeenteCode>
                    <oz:AKRKadastraleGemeenteCode>
                        <t:code>812</t:code>
                        <t:waarde>OTL02</t:waarde>
                    </oz:AKRKadastraleGemeenteCode>
                </oz:aKRKadastraleGemeenteCode>
            </oz:TypeKadastraleAanduiding>
        </oz:kadastraleAanduiding>
        <oz:begrenzingPerceel><gml:Polygon xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" gml:id="GEOMETRY_d68dfb9b-728b-411f-88be-f3c90cb54237" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992"><gml:exterior><gml:LinearRing><gml:posList>181182.346 456712.174 181196.546 456703.704 181203.710 456699.711 181208.183 456707.260 181186.952 456719.878 181182.346 456712.174</gml:posList></gml:LinearRing></gml:exterior></gml:Polygon></oz:begrenzingPerceel>
        <oz:kadastraleGrootte>
            <oz:TypeOppervlak>
                <oz:waarde>222</oz:waarde>
                <oz:soortGrootte>
                    <oz:SoortGrootte>
                        <t:code>1</t:code>
                        <t:waarde>Vastgesteld</t:waarde>
                    </oz:SoortGrootte>
                </oz:soortGrootte>
            </oz:TypeOppervlak>
        </oz:kadastraleGrootte>
        <oz:perceelnummerRotatie>0.0</oz:perceelnummerRotatie>
        <oz:perceelnummerVerschuiving>
            <oz:TypePerceelnummerVerschuiving>
                <oz:deltaX>0.0</oz:deltaX>
                <oz:deltaY>0.0</oz:deltaY>
            </oz:TypePerceelnummerVerschuiving>
        </oz:perceelnummerVerschuiving>
        <oz:plaatscoordinaten><gml:Point xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" gml:id="GEOMETRY_061c9c35-c29f-45df-8e5f-9c7fabcf3f82" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::28992"><gml:pos>181202.040 456706.351</gml:pos></gml:Point></oz:plaatscoordinaten>
    </oz:Perceel>
</kk:perceelMember>
</kk:DKK>


Ogr2ogr may be able to do the job with some clever SQL but it is certainly not developed for this kind of processing. I would rather study QGIS the geometry generator, or Python. However, maybe I will take this as an ogr2ogr challenge once I have some free time.

I edited your test data to include some offsets.
    <oz:TypePerceelnummerVerschuiving>
            <oz:deltaX>15.0</oz:deltaX>
            <oz:deltaY>-30.0</oz:deltaY>
    </oz:TypePerceelnummerVerschuiving>

With the GDAL SQLite dialect https://gdal.org/user/sql_sqlite_dialect.html and the SpatiaLite functions https://gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html it is possible to do the following:

select the point geometry
shift the point by the offsets
make a line between the original point and the shifted one

ogrinfo test.gml -dialect SQLite -sql "select MakeLine(geometry,shiftcoordinates(geometry,deltaX,deltaY)) as generated_geometry from perceel"
...
Geometry Column = generated_geometry
OGRFeature(SELECT):0
LINESTRING (181202.04 456706.351,181217.04 456676.351)

Notice that probably you should enhance the SQL and apply it only when  deltaX and deltaY are not both zeroes.
EDIT
Feature IDs are managed in a special way by GDAL. They are identifiers which, for example, should not be edited manually by users. However, it is possible to fiddle with SQL and select the FID field as a normal attribute.
ogrinfo test.gml -dialect SQLite -sql "select gml_id as my_id, MakeLine(geometry,shiftcoordinates(geometry,deltaX,deltaY)) as generated_geometry from perceel"
...
OGRFeature(SELECT):0
  my_id (String) = NL.IMKAD.KadastraalObject.84920229870000
  LINESTRING (181202.04 456706.351,181217.04 456676.351)


Thx, I'll try this out

It works, using the commands

It works, using the command: ogr2ogr -lco COORDINATE_PRECISION=9 -f "GeoJSON" bijpijlen.geojson -t_srs "EPSG:4326" kadastralekaart_perceel.gml -dialect SQLite -sql "select MakeLine(geometry,shiftcoordinates(geometry,deltaX,deltaY)) as generated_geometry from perceel where deltaX<>0 or deltaY<>0"

Interestingly, precision had to be set to a minimum of 8. Otherwise in some cases the offset was too small resulting in a Point geometry instead of Line.
A similar issue occurred when converting and extracting the polygons using the command: ogr2ogr -lco COORDINATE_PRECISION=8 -f "GeoJSON" kadastralekaart_perceelgrenzen.geojson -t_srs "EPSG:4326" kadastralekaart_perceel.gml -select begrenzingPerceel.

Resulting for some features in Multipolygons or combinations of Polygons and LineStrings for a single feature. Where in Qgis this doesn't occur.
Apparently the conversion and rounding off to x decimals happens first before the translation to polygons or line strings, etc.? Does the order in which the options in de command are placed have anything influence on this?

The source data seem to have a precision of millimeter. In GeoJSON the unit is degree, and 1 degree is about 111 kilometers. 8 decimals is not even enough for millimeters https://support.garmin.com/en-US/?faq=hRMBoCTy5a7HqVkxukhHd8. If you read the original GML with QGIS it does not need to do any conversion into degrees.

Thx. Interesting. Would you recommend to put the limitation to 8 decimals in a separate ogr2ogr command / step after the reprojection etc.? The limitation to a smaller number of decimals is necessary for me to keep the file size acceptable and I don't need an accuracy of millimetres for my purpose.

And perhaps more important: is there a way to change my ogr2ogr commands in such a way that the field: <oz:Perceel gml:id="NL.IMKAD.KadastraalObject.84920229870000">
is included in de output GeoJSON file?
Including Perceel gml:id in the select statement didn't work:
-dialect SQLite -sql "select Perceel gml:id,MakeLine(geometry,shiftcoordinates(geometry,deltaX,deltaY)) as generated_geometry from perceel where deltaX<>0 or deltaY<>0"
The field: <ko:identificatie domein="NL.IMKAD.KadastraalObject">84920229870000</ko:identificatie>
holds the same information and would also be ok.

There is a way but it is not so obvious. See the edited answer. When it comes to decimals, simply cutting decimals may lead into topology errors.  Experiment with your data and see what happens.
